# Why don't electrons gain potential energy as they near the positive terminal of a battery?

Tags: electric-current, potential-energy

If electrons move through the wire because of the force applied by the electric field that attracts them from negative terminal to positive terminal and this force is setting them to motion in a direction not opposing to the direction of the force, why don't they gain potential energy as there is work being done on them?

And like this even if they lose the potential energy, they gained from the chemical reactions inside the battery, on a lamp or a resistor they should gain some energy as they move.

Answer (score 0):

You are partially correct, as Potential  due to a positive charge is given by V= $\frac {kq}{r}$. As an electron moves towards a proton it goes from a region of lower potential to higher potential. But I assume that you know $\Delta U$=$\Delta$Vq. Hence Change in Potential energy is equal to Change in potential multiplied by Charge as Change in Potential is positive, also as q is negative Change in Potential Energy is negative and electron loses Potential Energy and gains Kinetic Velocity.  Hope you understand. Cheers

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know what ∆U= ∆Vq or V= kq/r means. My teacher did the worst thing ever she gave us the magnetism and electricity unit without giving us the general physics unit first which explained force, potential energy, power...etc. I only started searching for them when I found that the electricity rules didn't make sense. Anyway I'll google it ;)

Comment: I suggest you read from Haliday Resnick or University Physics by Sears and Zarnecky

Comment: Also to make it simpler all I'm saying is that the original potential energy it had is getting converted into kinetic energy and so potential energy is lost because kinetic is gained

Comment: Do you know Ohm's law?

Comment: But like that every time sb would apply a work on sth and it *moved*, the potential energy that that thing gained would be lost as kinetic energy.... And yes I know Ohm's law and rules regarding power too (how come my teacher explained them if we weren't introduced to terms like force, work and power first—idk) but unfortunately we're not going to cover the rules Naruto Uchiha wrote above, I checked the syllabus.

Comment: @Manar I am not able to understand what you are not able to understand.

Comment: If the electrons had moved without changing its velocity then yes they would've gained potential energy. That's exactly what happens when current moves across a resistor, it loses potential energy but it doesn't gain kinetic energy rather heat is dissipated across a resistor.

Comment: @Naruto Uchiha I'm sorry maybe I wasn't clear enough. But you said, "original potential energy it had is getting converted into kinetic energy and so potential energy is lost because kinetic is gained." Which I understood to mean that as an electron moves out of a resistor and into a wire, with no resistors, and nears the positive terminal, it will moves gaining potential energy from the force applied on it (like how I said in my original question) but this potential energy will be lost as kinetic energy.

Comment: I'm not able to understand why it will be lost as kinetic energy because as far as I understand current moves in a constant velocity.

Comment: Inside a resistor, there is a potential difference hence current will accelerate but we see that this doesn't happen rather the loss in potential energy comes out as Heat